# Function to check new registration

Tags: javascript, php

I want the edit button to only be active when there is a new record and until midnight the same day.
**Button**:

```
<a type="button" name="edit3" id="'.$row["Id"].','.$row["IdConsulta"].'" data-toggle="modal" href="#add_data_Modal3" onclick="minhafuncao()" class="btn btn-primary edit_data3">Editar</a>
```

Script to enable and disable button if new record exists:

```
function minhafuncao(){
    var dataHora = Date.now();
    var meiaNoite = '23:59';

    if(data && dataHora < meiaNoite){
        $('.edit_data3').prop("disabled",false);
    } else {
        $('.edit_data3').prop("disabled",true);
    }
}
```

When I run I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

`data` has to check if there was a new record in the database, but I am not realizing how to create the function to check it.

In this case I'm calling my `ajax` `data`.

```
$('#insert_form7').on("submit", function(event){  
    event.preventDefault(); 

    if($('#CodigoUtente6').val() == "") {  
        alert("Código Utente é necessário");  
    } else if($('#Descricao1').val() == "") {  
        alert("Observação é necessária");  
    } else {  
        $.ajax({  
            url:".conexao9",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:$('#insert_form7').serialize(),  
            beforeSend:function(){  
                $('#insert3').val("Inserting");  
            },                  
            success:function(data){ 
                $('#insert_form7')[0].reset();  
                $('#add_data_Modal3').modal('hide');  
                $('#employee_table').html(data); 
                location.reload("add_data_Modal3");                         
            }
        });  
    }  
});
```

Comment: data is not define in your minhafuncao() function. you have to pass data into your function.

Comment: @Sfili_81 And how do I pass the data to the function, I've already tried `data = $ _POST ["data"];` but I get the error $ _POST is not defined

Comment: Also you shouldn't rely on client's time if the restriction you set is for a serious purpose, it can easily get cheated by changing the client's machine time (for example the server could sent the time along with `data`)

Comment: as another note: inline js is a bad practice, you have access to jQuery so just use .click in there ..

Comment: @Kaddath How can I then prevent time being changed on the server, can you put an example?

Comment: @treyBake You can put an example like doing with `jquery`

Comment: Your server is supposed to have a reliable time, but when a page runs `Date.now();` on a client browser in JavaScript, you get the client's time, not the server time.

Comment: @Bruno `$('#foo').click(function(){//code you want to run})`

Comment: @treyBake I added the code with your suggestion to the question but I think it will not be correct, can you check?

Comment: @Bruno my foo code is example code - not copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST[‘data’]{// to check if it is data in    post
// code
}
```

Comment: As I apply in my code, can you put the complete example?

Comment: @Bruno send your php code you wrote that you can not pass the data in you function from POST.